# Xna destructible walls

Tags: c#, xna, pixel, monogame, destruction

So I'm making a space invaders clone and I'm stuck on the wall part. I need to make destructible wall I don't know how to do it. So if anyone has any idea, it would be helpful to get some help from you people out there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us what you have tried so far with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Do not hesitate reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's recommended that you first try it yourself before asking an question, as there are many ways to implement such a thing. One example (And doesn't have to be the best one) is to make an object for every destructable part, which destroys if it hits. This could work in the original Space Invaders, as these walls are only build with a few pixels.

Comment: I have tried that exact example but I was asking for any other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original Space Invaders had barricades that got destroyed pixel by pixel by the explosions of bullets that hit them. So if you want to make it realistic, when you detect a per-pixel collision of a bullet with a wall, draw the explosion and at the same time remove those pixels from the wall texture where they overlap.

The original arcade version never actually redrew the whole screen every frame so this process was automatic when the explosion disappeared. It never moved more than 4 or 5 objects each frame.

Of course you will have to manage rebuilding the 4 walls from the original undamaged texture every level. Happy programming.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand but how would I remove the pixels? With texture.SetData();?

Comment: Yes if I remember right. Read the data into a Color array with GetData(), access it and write changes with SetData().